# Java RSTALanguageSupport : Cannot register RSyntaxTextArea

Tags: java, html, autocomplete, rsyntaxtextarea

I am using RSyntaxTextArea and RSTALanguageSupport for a project. I tried to register the RSyntaxTextArea by doing :

```
textArea = new RSyntaxTextArea();
textArea.setSyntaxEditingStyle(SyntaxConstants.);
LanguageSupportFactory.get().register(textArea);
```

But it says : Cannot find org.fife.ui.autocomplete.CompletionProvider 
So I added the AutoCompletion library. Then it says :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.fife.rsta.ac.html.HtmlCellRenderer.getIcon(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljavax/swing/Icon;
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please help me